# Trying to create my first project in angular

Tags: angular

Im running the ng new name and an error occurred. Do you have any idea why is this happening?

ng : File C:\Users\nraftis\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see
about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1

- ng new grid-list
- ~~

  - CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess

Comment: Do you have admin rights on your machine?

Comment: windows... if u want to be a good developer - try to use linux/macos. more simple to start any application

Comment: Follow the link given to you in the error message (and if it leads to a 404, simply google `Execution Policies powershell`, by default script execution in powershell is disabled, you just need to enable it. You will find all the information as well as the implications of doing so on Microsoft's website

Answer (score 1):

ok i found the solution.

1. run as adninistrator Powershell
2. run " Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser""
3. set ExecutionPolicy: Unrestricted

and its done!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMYyq.png)